# How to add quotes in the file

Tags: python, regex, shell

I have file below

```
123,PEN BOOK
124,BALL
125,BOOK
126,PENCIL BOOK
```

I need to add quotes

Expected out

```
"123","PEN BOOK"
"124","BALL"
"125","BOOK"
"126","PENCIL BOOK"
```

Comment: Is `shell` tag appropriate here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have a file `test.txt` with the following content:

```
123,PEN
124,BALL
125,BOOK
126,PENCIL
```

You can use a code like the following, to create a temp file with the content with quotes and replace the original file:

```
import os 
with open("test.txt") as i: # open file for reading, i = input file 
  with open("temp.txt", "w") as o: # open temp file in write mode, o = output 
     for l in i: # read each line
        o.write('"{}","{}"\n'.format(l.split(',')[0],l.split(',')[1].split('\n')[0]))

os.remove('test.txt')                    # remove the old file
os.rename('temp.txt','test.txt')         # resave the temp file as the new file
```

Output:

```
"123","PEN"
"124","BALL"
"125","BOOK"
"126","PENCIL"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've updated my answer to cover additional case of text containing spaces.

Seeing as you have a `regex` tag in your question, you can use something like this:

```
import re

text = """123,PEN
124,BALL
125,BOOK
126,PENCIL
123,PEN BOOK"""

new_text = re.sub(r'(\d+),([\w\s]+)$', r'"\1","\2"', text, flags=re.M)
```

Comment: `awk -F',' '{printf "\"%s\",\"%s\"\n", $1,$2}' <your-file>`

Comment: can you check one more condition `123,PEN BOOK` expected out is `"123,PEN BOOK "`